Calculate $E(X^2)$ from $E(X)$?

I have a random variable $N$ with $P(N=k) = 0.5^k$ for $k=1,2...$
Expected value is given by:
$$E(X) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}0.5^kk$$

I know this is a geometric series, can solve it and get: $$E(X) = 2$$
However, I cannot figure out how to define and calculate $$E(X^2)$$
Any suggestions are appreciated

This is not enough information  but I suppose you know $P(n)$ it seems to be a geometrical law there are probably dozens of answers online

I've updated the description with relevant information. What I am struggling with is actually defining what E(X^2) looks like

How would you define $ E(X^2)$? Or $E( \frac{1}{X})$?

The expected value of $X^2$ is defined as $$E(X^2) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X=k)k^2 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^kk^2$$
In order to calculate this series, notice that it is the same as $g(1/2)$, where $g(x)= \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2x^k$.
Now, using the formula for the sum of a geometric series, $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k=\dfrac{x}{1-x}$$
Thus, $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (k+2)(k+1)x^{k }-2=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+2)(k+1)x^{k }=\sum_{k=2}^\infty k(k-1)x^{k-2}=\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k\right)''=\\\left(\dfrac{x}{1-x}\right)''=\frac{2x}{(1-x)^3}+\frac{2}{(1-x)^2}$$
Evaluating at $x=1/2$ (and expanding the first sum) we find $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k }+\sum_{k=1}^\infty 3k\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k }+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k }=14$$
But, using that $E(X)=2$, $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty 3k\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k }=3\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k }=6$$
and by the geometric series sum formula, $$2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k }=2,$$
from where $$E(X^2) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^kk^2=14-6-2=6$$

Thanks a lot for the elaborate answer!

As others have shown, you can calculate $E(X^2)$ from the original data but this is not what you asked in the title.  You cannot calculate $E(X^2)$ from $E(X)$ without knowing the original data.  Let's look at two very simple examples:
$X$ may only take the value $1$ (with probability $1$ of course).  $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$ are both $1$.
$X$ may take the value $1$ or $-1$ with equal probability.  $E(X)$ is now $0$ but $E(X^2)$ is still $1$.
You can say very little about $E(X^2)$ if you only know $E(X)$.  If you know that $X$ is real then $E(X) \ne 0$ will tell you that $E(X^2) \ne 0$ but we have seen that even the converse of this simple case is not necessarily true.

Now that you've clarified that you're talking about the geometric distribution for $p=0.5$, the calculation is simple.
$$E(X) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X=k)k = \sum_{k=1}^\infty 0.5^kk = 2$$
$$E(X^2) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X=k)k^2 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty 0.5^kk^2 = 6$$
All you do is replace $k$ in the summation by $k^2$.

Now that you write it it looks obvious
